# gcloud disk snapshot - how to restore?

Tags: gcloud, snapshot

I created a snapshot of one of my disks in gcloud. I can see the new snapshot listed in the "snapshots" tab.

**How can I now recreate this disk?** - I want to test the recovery of an backup.

I followed this instructions and created a new instance with the disk attached:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/restore-and-delete-snapshots

[image]

I ssh´ed to the instance then and tried to find the disk, but it seems not to be attached? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found it out. The disk needs to be mounted:

```
mkdir /demo-mount
sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/sdb /demo-mount
```